# Как ускорить Resharper на Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Есть VS 2015 update 1 и солюшен на 100 проектов (конкртетно вот этот: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard).

На VS 2013 всё работает более-менее. Но на VS 2015 студия периодически просто подвисает секунд на 20-30.
Конфигурация: Win10, 16GB RAM, Core i7 3630, SSD

Есть ли способ ускорить R# на VS 2015?

Comment: Думаю, этот вопрос вам лучше тут задать: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/resharper, предварительно прочитав это: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37228482 и это: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104498-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow

Comment: Так же столкнулся с такой же проблемой.
Советую разбить одно большое решение на несколько маленьких. Так же, если нажать на кнопку в правом нижнем углу, можно подчистить мусор, собранный ReSharper'ом вручную.

К слову, советую разбивать проект на отдельные модули, приложения и динамичные библиотеки по мере возможности, так как одно большое решение - всегда сложно для IDE с данной модификацией. Так же просмотрите настройки ReSharper'а и отключите ненужные вам модули.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в том, что VS2015 пока работает не особо устойчиво. У меня на компе те же характеристики почти, только у меня Win8.1 и i5, она бывает подвисает на 3-5 секунд, но редко. В 13 такого не наблюдаю. Еще есть вариант, если свободного места на SSD маловато, то будет тупить VS совместно с Windows. А еще накатили обновление TFS до 15, так он со студий 15 вместе любит тупить. Почему грешишь на Resharper? какая версия, кстати, стоит?

Comment: Так потому, что если решарпер выключить, то студия перестаёт подвисать. Места на SSD достаточно. Похоже, проблема в анализаторе R#.
ReSharper 10.0.20151101.194151

Comment: @musuk, у меня ReSharper 9.2... Напишите в службу поддержки о проблеме, думаю они подскажут. (Если Вы являетесь обладателем лицензии)

Comment: Попробуйте обновить ReSharper. Возможно проблема была устранена на более поздних версиях.